# Prove that there are insufficent information with each side length known to calculate area of any irregular polyogon that have more than three side

Tags: geometry

Prove that there are insufficent information with each side length known in order to calculate the area of any irregular polyogon that have more than three side?

I found that i have been having great diffuculty to doing this even with my college geometry texts!

Comment: Try quadrilaterals to start with. Can you demonstrate that any quadrilateral can be deformed to a non-similar quadrilateral having the same side lengths?

Comment: If one side has length equal to the sum of the remaining sides, any polygon built from them is degenerate and has zero area.

Comment: @MarkBennet - Not the degernerate one :)

Comment: @LeeMosher - How to prove that they have different area?

Comment: @LeeMosher - How to prove that the polygon with same side length can have different area?

Comment: I would suggest playing with some examples to get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably proof by counterexample: find two irregular polygons (quadrilaterals, say) with an equal number of sides of equal lengths, and show that they do not have the same area.